# A way to always filter query results with Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using an `OrgID` on all my models in an ASP.NET application using EF as a way to partition the database. I do this so that the database can be shared among multiple users while ensuring that only the data of their organization is available to them.

This forces me to write this `OrgID` with every insert and to filter every call I make to the database.

So for instance I query the current user's `OrgID` and insert this in my controllers' `Update` methods like this:

```
store.OrgID = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User).OrgID;
_context.Update(store);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Then when I want to list out objects I again need to filter by `OrgID`:

```
var orgID = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User).OrgID;
var stores = await _context.Stores.Where(s => s.OrgID == orgID).ToListAsync();
```

I'd love to find a way to override the `ApplicationDBContext` so that these are handled automatically otherwise it's quite a tedious and error prone task to always handle this in every call to the database.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an interface that has the OrgID :

```cs
public interface IOrgID
{
    public int OrgID { get; set; }
}
```

All your models must implement this interface e.g.:

```cs
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, IOrgID
{
    public int OrgID { get; set; }

    //...
}

public class Stores : IOrgID
{
    public int OrgID { get; set; }

    //...
}
```

Use generic repository and create CRUD methods considering the OrgID from the currently logged in user:

```cs
public class MyRepo
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
        private readonly int _orgID;

        public MyRepo(ApplicationDbContext context, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        {
            _context = context;
            _accessor = accessor;

            var userId = _accessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            _orgID = _context.Users.Find(userId).OrgID;
        }

        public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExp)
            where T : class, IOrgId
        {
            return await _context.Set<T>().Where(x => x.OrgId == _orgID).FirstOrDefaultAsync(whereExp);
        }

        public async Task<bool> Create<T>(T entitiy)
            where T : class, IOrgId
        {
            _context.Set<T>().Add(entitiy);
            return await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
        }

        public async Task<bool> UpdateAsync<T>(T entity)
            where T : class, IOrgId
        {
            _context.Entry<T>(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            return await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ListAsync<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExp)
            where T : class, IOrgId
        {
            return await _context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.OrgId == _orgID).Where(whereExp).ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<bool> DeleteAync<T>(T entity)
            where T : class, IOrgId
        {
            _context.Entry<T>(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            return await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters).

> Global query filters are LINQ query predicates (a boolean expression
>   typically passed to the LINQ Where query operator) applied to Entity
>   Types in the metadata model (usually in OnModelCreating). Such filters
>   are automatically applied to any LINQ queries involving those Entity
>   Types, including Entity Types referenced indirectly, such as through
>   the use of Include or direct navigation property references.

Comment: Interesting but this suggests many applications hitting the same database as you have to specify the TenantID (OrgID in my case) within the startup ConfigureService method. I am using a different tenancy model whereby I have multiple tenants at the application level as well. Still solves another requirement I had for soft deletes.

Answer (score 0):

What people do I this case is create a class wrapping the `DbContext` and exposing methods that make sense for their business logic. In your case you can make a `UserRepository`/`StoreRepository` classes where the search methods require a `origID` paramamter

```
public class StoreRepository {

    private ApplicationDBContext _context

    StoreRepository(ApplicationDBContext context){
     _context = context
    }

    public Task<Ilist<Store>> GetStores(int origID){
       return _context.Stores.Where(s => s.OrgID == orgID).ToListAsync();
    } 
}
```

Comment: calling `ToListAsync()` will cause performance problems because it will execute the query and return a full list of dataset entites.

Comment: another approach can be by returning `IQueryable` and remove `.ToListAsync()`, so the method will return a query and not entities.